# SQL Server query optimization using indexes on tables

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I have this query in a SQL Server function which takes around 3 seconds to execute for a single value. It adds up the time when the function is called for large number of records.

I'm showing the structure of tables and the existing indexes. Just checking suggestions if there is any indexes which I can add to get a better performance this query

For example - for Table B joined with Table U on `PId` column.
Current index `[IX_TableB_2]` is on `PRId` which is used in condition in `WHERE` clause for  `b.PRID <> @PRID`.

Is there a better index suggestion for these tables for this particular query?

Thanks

```
--Query
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC), b.BId, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    TableB b
INNER JOIN 
    TableU u ON u.PID = b.PID
LEFT JOIN 
    TableP p ON p.BName = b.BName
WHERE 
    LEFT(b.Code, @CheckLen) = LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen)
    AND b.PRID <> @PRID                 
    AND ISNULL(p.DSID, @DSID) = @DSID   
GROUP BY 
    b.BId
```

Table row counts and structure

- TableB: 1 million rows

[image]

```
--Existing Indexes on the TableB
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableB_1] 
ON [TableB] ([Code] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableB_2] 
ON [TableB] ([PRID] ASC)
INCLUDE([Code], [BId], [BName], [PID])
```

- TableU: 3 million rows

[image]

```
--Existing Indexes on TableU

ALTER TABLE TableU 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TableU] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PID] ASC)
```

- TableP: 600 rows

[image]

```
--Existing Indexes on TableP
ALTER TABLE TableP 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TableP] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BName ASC, DSID ASC)
```

Comment: This design is seriously flawed, your filtering arguments are *not sargable*, you should never use an expression/function to derive a column, eg `WHERE LEFT(b.Code,@CheckLen)` can never use an index seek, you are forcing SQL Server to scan every row.

Comment: `LEFT(b.Code, @CheckLen) = LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen)` can be made sargable as `b.Code LIKE LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen) + '%'`

Comment: First of all, please paste your execution plan at pastetheplan.com and link to it from you original post. Second, as others have said, you have non SARGABLE where conditions. No index will be able to use those, as they're currently written. Reviewing your execution plans should show you this.

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks for pointing out that mistake. corrected the query.

Comment: Fyi, for posting query plans https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: We need to see the execution plans, this is not answerable otherwise

Comment: @Charlieface - plan pasted in https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1Z3X8a-5

Comment: Can I just confirm the logic of `AND ISNULL(p.DSID, @DSID) = @DSID` Given that the `DSID` columns is not nullable, it is checking that a row for which `TableP` was joined has a matching `DSID` value, but for rows that the `LEFT JOIN` failed, it is also allowing. Was that the intention? So you could instead use `LEFT JOIN TableP p ON p.BName = b.BName AND p.DSID = @DSID` and get the same result?

Comment: Also which of the other two clauses is more likely to limit the number of rows `LEFT(b.Code, @CheckLen) = LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen)` or `b.PRID <> @PRID`

Comment: @Charlieface - You are right - I can use `p.DSID = @DSID` in `LEFT JOIN` instead of `AND ISNULL(p.DSID, @DSID) = @DSID` in `WHERE`. `LEFT(b.Code, @CheckLen) = LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen)` limits the number of rows more than `b.PRID <> @PRID` .

Comment: Actually thinking about that `LEFT JOIN` the logic is slightly different: your version would exclude rows if the join succeeded but the `DSID` does not exclude any rows at all. Ergo, you can use the following syntax for the same effect `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableP p WHERE p.BName = b.BName AND p.DSID <> @DSID)` and that should be able to hit the index properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the filter on `LEFT(b.Code, @CheckLen)` will limit the rows coming out of `TableB` more than the filter `<> @PRID`. So it's better to just rely on the clustered index on `Code`. To hit the index you will need to change your `WHERE` clause

```sql
b.Code LIKE LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen) + '%'
```

Furthermore, the left-join on `TableP` is then filtered in the `WHERE` using `ISNULL`. Given that `DSID` is not nullable, the logic can be flipped around into a `NOT EXISTS`. The index is correct as it stands: first the equality on `BName`, then the inequality on `DSID`.

```sql
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TableP p
    WHERE p.BName = b.BName
      AND p.DSID <> @DSID
)
```

The lookup on `TableU` is already using the clustered index, there are no other columns, so nothing can be done there.

The grouping on `BId` cannot be helped here. Because the filter on `Code` is a range lookup, any columns coming afterwards in the index key cannot be used. But it shouldn't matter much, because you appear to have only have 13 rows before grouping after all the joins, and only one `BId` value, so performance should be fine.

The `ROW_NUMBER` is going to cause you problems, as it requires an extra sort on `COUNT(*)`. If there is any way you can remove it I would advise to do so.

Putting that all together

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC), b.BId, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    TableB b
INNER JOIN
    TableU u ON u.PID = b.PID
WHERE 
    b.Code LIKE LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen) + '%'
    AND b.PRID <> @PRID
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM TableP p
        WHERE p.BName = b.BName
          AND p.DSID <> @DSID
    )
GROUP BY 
    b.BId;
```

There are no index changes you need to make, although you may now drop the non-clustered index on `TableB`.

---

Alternatively, it may be that the logic of that left-join was wrong in the first place, and really all you need is to move the condition into the `ON`

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC), b.BId, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    TableB b
INNER JOIN
    TableU u ON u.PID = b.PID
LEFT JOIN
    TableP p ON p.BName = b.BName
            AND p.DSID = @DSID
WHERE 
    b.Code LIKE LEFT(@Code, @CheckLen) + '%'
    AND b.PRID <> @PRID
GROUP BY 
    b.BId;
```

Note that this version has different results: it will not exclude any rows from the other tables.

The indexes should be the same.